# Android Blend transparent png image on existing background

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to create a Analog Meter in OpenGL ES 1.x on Android. I have created a simple circle using Midpoint Theorem in green color. Now I want to place some numbers around the circle for Meter readings. Since OpenGL has no native text rendering API, I am trying to load an PNG image like this [image] with the reading on it and the rest of image is transparent.

Now what parameters I must pass to glBlendFunc() function to achive this. 
I have tried many different combinations but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem on Android.  You can't use the Android Bitmap class to load textures that have transparent areas in them.  This is because Bitmap follows the Porter-Duff specification for alpha blending, and Bitmap optimizes images with per-pixel alpha by storing them in the premultiplied format (A, R*A, G*A, B*A). This is great for Porter-Duff but not for OpenGL, which requires a non-premultiplied (ARGB) format. This means that the Bitmap class can only be used with textures that are completely opaque (or have no per-pixel alpha).  This article details:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Just try passing the Alpha Blending values which are:

```
glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I hope it helps.

I don't think(even at 2.2)Alpha PNGs are problem for the Android Bitmap loading algorithm.